# Authentication required for every 1 hour for Internet but NO proxy. How do I get out from this problem?

Tags: networking, apt, software-center, proxy, authentication

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 and/or above

My system connected to University campus Internet which has no proxy. But needs authentication (username and password) for every 1 hour. If the web-browser is running with authentication, then no problem for updating/installing packages. But if the web-browser is off or timed out for authentication, then Update/installation can't be done.

How do I set it right?

Here is a screenshot of the authentication:[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you provide details about how exactly you login via browser? A screenshot would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I assume they are using a *transparent proxy*, that is one you don't normally see at all.

You can get to the authentication page again by opening a **new tab/window** in your browser and try to connect to any web server from there. After reauthenticating you can proceed as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to submit that form (the one mentioned in the screenshot in the comment section of question) again and again every hour to the proxy server.

So basically you are looking at hitting a particular URL automatically. This is same as "generating load" on the server at the rate of 1 link per hour.

Basic load generation softwares like jmeter should do the trick.

You should use the 'Jmeter proxy' to create the jmeter profile required for auto-hitting the link. [This manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Proxy_Server) will help with that. Once you have that, keep the jmeter running so that it hits the server once every 55 minutes, and you should have good a non-interrupted connection !!

I am assuming that you have the experience and expertise to use jmeter.